# How to find the number of combinations given certain parameters?

Tags: combinations

I need to find out the number of possible combinations for the following, and would like to understand the working behind it as well.

I have a product that consists of 3 separate parts, head, arms and legs.

The product must always have the 3 parts present and must always be in the order head > arms > legs.

If I have 2 products, I could swap the heads for example. Then maybe swap the legs.

So, given these parameters, how many different combinations could I get if I have a collection of 6 products?

Comment: do each of the 6 products have distinct heads,arms, and legs?

Comment: Sorry, yes. All 6 products have distinct pieces. So one head is different to all the other heads etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it as $6$ teams of $3$ being formed.

The $6$ "heads" are allowed to choose one each of a set of "arms" and "legs"

The $1st$ head can select its team in $6\cdot6 = 6^2$ ways.

Now only $5$ sets of arms and legs are left to choose from for the $2nd$ head,
who has $5\cdot5 = 5^2$ choices, and so on.

Thus # of different teams possible $= (6\cdot 5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1)^2 = (6!)^2 = 518400$

**PS**
Note that the above counts the number of **divisions** into $6$ products using all the parts. If each product in such a division is to be counted, you need to multiply by $6$

Comment: Why isn't it (6!)^3? As there are 3 pieces?  Also remember that a product has to be in order, head then arms then legs.

Comment: For any **given** "head" $(H)$, we can only choose $A$ and $L$ , so (6!)^2. Also, since we are only *choosing* $H-A-L,$ we can always assemble them in correct order. Why don't you enumerate all possibilities for two sets each of $H,A,L$

Comment: I did (6!)^2 and I get an answer of 518,400

Comment: My bad ! Typo corrected !

Comment: Surely the fact you are choosing a head first means it's to the power of 3,as there are 3 parts?

Comment: Take the case of $2$ each of $H,A,L$. Withh $H1$, you can only make $H_1A_1L_1, \;H_1A_1L_2,\; H_1A_2L_1,\; H_1A_2L_2$  so there will be only $2^2 = 4$ sets with each type of head (i.e. 4 divisions into teams in my solution) If you want to count each team $=$ each product, for the above case you need to multiply by $2$, and for the $6$ case, multiply by $6$

Comment: I don't quite understand your PS edit. What do I need to multiply by 6?

Comment: For the $2$ case, each head can give rise to $4$ products, so $4\times2$ total products. But if you put all you can make using all the parts, and put them in a display window, there can only be $4$ at a time. Same thing for $6$. There can be $518,400$ displays at a time, but $6$ times as many distinct products possible.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by "but 6 times as many distinct products possbile"?

Comment: For the two heads case, if you want to display in a window using all parts at any one time, you have 4 sets: **H1A1L1 - H2A2L2 or H1A1L2 - H2A2L1 or H1A2L1 - H2A1L2 or H1A2L2 - H2A1L1**, but there are 8 products i.e twice as many products, because each of 2 heads forms a product. Similarly for 6 heads.

Comment: I've just come back to this for some clarity, and still don't understand the last part I'm afraid. Let's stick with the example of having 6 separate, 3-piece characters. Say I want to display 6 characters in a window, each day changing the combination to one of the unique combinations. Is that just `(6!)^2` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have $6$ products, then you have $6$ heads, $6$ arms, and $6$ legs.  Building a new product from these parts is picking $1$ head, $1$ arm, and $1$ leg from each of the piles of $6$, so you have $6\cdot6\cdot6=6^3$ possible products.

Comment: I need to remake 6 full products, not just 1 from the total parts.